# how to hide a button for 10 min with pure js and html

Tags: javascript, html

I was using jQuery but I would like to just have JS and HTML hide this button for 10 minuets. jQuery code:

```js
setInterval(function() {}, 100);
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".hide").css("visibility", "visible");
}, 600000);
```

```html
<div class="hide" style="visibility:hidden">
  <button class="cool_button" onclick="buyMegaMiner()">
    Hire MegaMiner
  </button>
</div>
```

I would like to do the same thing but with pure js and html

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
$(".hide").css("visibility", "visible");
```

with

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hide")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: I need it to work on 3 buttons using the same class.

Comment: works for three class's using --->    setInterval(function() {}, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("hide(1)")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementsByClassName("hide(2)")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementsByClassName("hide(3)")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
    }, 600000);